# how can i pass a value from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

This is part of my jsp program.

```
<%@ page import="db.Conn" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%  try{
    String id2=request.getParameter("id");


    System.out.println(id2);



%>      
<input type="hidden" name="id2" id="id2" value="<%=id2%>" >

<%  }catch(Exception e)
    {System.err.println(e);}
%>

<form method="Post" action="./transaction">

    <button type="submit">Pay Now</button>

</form>
</span></div>
```

But when i try to get this id2 in my servlet by using this statement:

```
String id=request.getParameter("id2");
```

I get `id=null`.
How can I get my value?

Answer (score 0):

The `input` tag element which stores the `id2` has to be inside the form element.

```
 <%@ page import="db.Conn" %>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

 <form method="Post" action="./transaction">

    <%  try{
        String id2=request.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println(id2);
    %>      
    <input type="hidden" name="id2" id="id2" value="<%=id2%>" >

    <%  }catch(Exception e)
        {System.err.println(e);}
    %>

        <button type="submit">Pay Now</button>

    </form>
    </span></div>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score -2):

Try using the JSTL core library. Add this to your JSP declarations:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Then you should be able to replace your <% %> code block with this:

```
<c:set var="id2" value="${id}"/>
```

Then you can use the variable id2 for anything in your JSP, including passing it to the servlet via an input tag.

Have you read the JSP tutorial? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html

Comment: can u please help me with the code. i need to submit it today in my college.

Comment: uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application.

Comment: @PulkitPansari Good to know you are concerned about your college work but learning the  latest coding techniques is also important. Get your hands-on *JSTL* quickly as *Scriplets* are obsolete.